# Server-side pagination for DataGrid in Syncfusion (Blazor Server App)

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, syncfusion

I'm working on a Blazor server app using Syncfusion UI components. I use the following codes for `Equipment Table` component:

```
<div>
    <SfGrid @ref="DefaultGrid" DataSource="@Equipments" EnableRtl="true" class="table-eq" AllowResizing="true" AllowSorting="true" AllowFiltering="true" AllowPaging="true" Height="@TableHeight.ToString()">
        <GridPageSettings PageSize="@PageSize" PageCount="PageCount"></GridPageSettings>
        <GridColumns>
            <GridColumn Field="EquipmentCode" HeaderText="Equipment Code" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="40"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field="EquipmentTitle" HeaderText="Equipment Title" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="120"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field="equipmentType.EquipmentTypeTitle" HeaderText="Equipment Type" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="60"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field="EquipmentCategory.CategoryName" HeaderText="Equipment Category" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="60"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field="CostCenter.Title" HeaderText="Cost Center" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="60"></GridColumn>
            <GridColumn Field="IsActive" HeaderText="Status" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="30"></GridColumn>
        </GridColumns>
    </SfGrid>
</div>
@code {
    SfGrid<Equipment> DefaultGrid;
    int totalCount;

    public static List<Equipment> Equipments { get; set; }

    public int TableHeight { get; set; } = 400;
    public int PageSize { get; set; } = 50;
    public int PageCount { get; set; } = 1;
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; } = 1;

    private void GetCurrentPage()
    {
        CurrentPage = DefaultGrid.PageSettings.CurrentPage;
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        totalCount = await Task.Run(() => equipmentServices.GetTotalEquipmentsCount());
        Equipments = await Task.Run(() => equipmentServices.GetPagedEquipmentsData(CurrentPage, PageSize));
        PageCount = (totalCount % PageSize) > 0 ? (totalCount / PageSize) - totalCount % PageSize : totalCount / PageSize;
    }

}
```

I use the following code to get paged data from database:

```
public async Task<List<Equipment>> GetPagedEquipmentsData(int pageNumber, int pageCapacity)
{
    int skip = (pageNumber - 1) * pageCapacity;

    var list = await _sqlServerContext.Equipments
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.EquipmentId)
        .Skip(skip).Take(pageCapacity)
        .Include(x => x.CostCenter)
        .Include(x => x.EquipmentCategory)
        .Include(x => x.equipmentType)
        .ToListAsync();

    return list;
}
```

When I run the app, only 50 records with 1 page is shown. I need to have `PageCount` number of pages in the bottom of table. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your calculation of `PageCount` is incorrect.
What you have is:

```
PageCount = (totalCount % PageSize) > 0 ? (totalCount / PageSize) - totalCount % PageSize : totalCount / PageSize;
```

I assume what you want is:

```
PageCount = (totalCount % PageSize) > 0 ? (totalCount / PageSize) + 1 : totalCount / PageSize;
```

(Note: Keep in mind that `+ 1` is sufficient because the result of `totalCount % PageSize` cannot be >= `PageSize`. Otherwise it would be eaten by `%`.)

But this still won't fix your issue completely... The thing is that you get `Equipment`s from `GetPagedEquipmentsData` where you do `.Skip(0)` and `.Take(50)`. From this you get the first 50 equipments. You take them and pass them to the grid (`DataSource="@Equipments"`). So the only equipments the grid knows about are those 50 and will do pagination on them. No more getting of equipments is performed.

So... the solution?
1.) You either get **ALL** of the equipments in the `GetPagedEquipmentsData` (just delete `Skip` and `Take`). This way you will have easily done paginated grid, but it might not be what you want...

2.) If your goal is to get data when you need them (when you're on the 1.page you want first 50 equipments from database (*or whatever data source*), when you're on the 2.page you want another 50 equipments from the database (*or whatever data source*) etc.). Then I think you have to use `SfDataManager` with `CustomAdaptor`.
There may be other ways how to do it but the one way is to create new component `YourCustomDataAdaptor` which inherits from Syncfusion's `DataAdaptor<T>`, override/implement its method(s) and then use it in the grid:

```
<SfGrid ...>
    <SfDataManager Adaptor="Adaptors.CustomAdaptor">
            <YourCustomDataAdaptor />
    </SfDataManager>
    ...
</SfGrid>
```

You can see more about custom adaptor (including examples how to use it) here: https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/datagrid/custom-binding

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, I suggest using the following code snippet to retrieve the PageCount of the Grid.

```
<SfButton OnClick="PageCount">PageCount</SfButton><SfGrid @ref="DefaultGrid" DataSource="@Orders" AllowPaging="true" Height="200">
```

private SfGrid DefaultGrid;

```
private void PageCount()
{
    var pagecount = (DefaultGrid.TotalItemCount % DefaultGrid.PageSettings.PageSize) > 0 ?
        (DefaultGrid.TotalItemCount / DefaultGrid.PageSettings.PageSize) + 1 :
    DefaultGrid.TotalItemCount / DefaultGrid.PageSettings.PageSize;
}
```